# Point within triangle maximally distant from four points

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a right triangle $ABC$ where the midpoint of the hypotenuse $AB$ is $M$, and the side $AC$ is longer than $BC$. How to determine the point $X$ within the triangle such that the distance from $X$ to any of $A$, $B$, $C$, $M$ is as great as possible? That is, the minimum of $XA$, $XB$, $XC$, $XM$ is maximal? I'm speculating it could be the centroid of $AMC$, but I'm really not sure. Thanks.

Comment: If the hypotenuse is $AB$ then $AC$ can't be the longest side. The hypotenuse is always longest.

Comment: @John, perhaps one is meant to understand "side" as "leg".

Comment: @GerryMyerson ...yes, perhaps. It would be nice to have that clarified, however.

Comment: Sorry, Gerry is right. That was slackness on my part.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Note that $M$ becomes the center of the circle circumscribing $ABC$. My gut feeling is that $X$ is the centroid of $BMC$, because of the acuteness of the angle $B-M-C$, but you could be right that it's the centroid of $AMC$.

Comment: @JoshuaCiappara : I gave this some thought -- if $X$ is a centroid of either $AMC$ or $BMC$, then it will be the centroid of $BMC$. To show this, let $AC$ become really long, almost as long as $AB$. Then $AMC$ is very skinny, and you can't find a point far from all three of $A$, $M$, and $C$ without choosing a point on one of the sides. When you do that though, you may as well choose a point inside $BMC$, which will be close to the midpoint of $MC$, but a little farther away (i.e., the centroid of $BMC$).

Comment: That makes sense John. Thanks. Of course, it remains to be seen whether either centroid should in fact be $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's solve a simpler problem. Given an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with vertex $C$, the point $X$ inside the triangle that maximizes the minimal distance from the three vertices is:

- the circumcenter, if it lies within the triangle (that is, if the triangle is acute);
- the intersection of $AB$ with the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, if the triangle is obtuse (that is, if angle $ACB$ is obtuse). We can also use the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ instead, by symmetry.

(For right isosceles triangles, take the limit in either case - we get the center of the hypotenuse $AB$.)

Now for the problem given: the point $X$ might be inside the acute isosceles triangle $BCM$, or it might be inside the obtuse isosceles triangle $ACM$.

- In the first case, any point inside $BCM$ is farther from $A$ than it is from $M$. So the best we can do is take $X$ to be the circumcenter of $BCM$.
- In the second case, let $N$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Any point in triangle $ANM$ has an analogous point in triangle $CNM$ (its reflection in the line $NM$0; but the point in $ANM$ is farther from $B$ than the analogous point in $CNM$. Therefore the best we can do is to take $X$ to be the intersection of $AN$ with the perpendicular bisector of $AM$.

These are the only two choices for $X$, and I believe one can show that the latter choice is always optimal.

Comment: You might be right in this answer, but your claims in the simpler problem (the dot points) aren't completely obvious to me. Could you elaborate on why they are true?

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of if you're NOT at the circumcentre, then your distance to some vertex is less than the radius of the circumcircle. What about dot point two?

Comment: Without loss of generality we're closer to $B$ than to $A$ (in the "bottom half" of the triangle), by symmetry. Then we're just trying to maximize the minimum of the distances to $B$ and $C$. Both distances are increasing as we go away from $BC$, so the optimum must be on the side $AB$ somewhere. But as we move along that side (between $B$ and the midpoint of $AB$), one distance increases while the other decreases. Therefore the highest minimum occurs when they are equal. And that means it must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.